# Iam using promise.all() to fetch a url with different parameters but it returns an array of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this array with a promise before this which is working fine but when it gives the array individually when I console the promises it works fine but when it comes to the end result of promise all it gives undefined

```
const prom = (leader) => {
  try {
    fetch(
      "http://example/api/junk?" +
        new URLSearchParams({
          //the elements of array goes here
          id: leader
        }),
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          token: token.id
        }
      }
    )
      .then((res) => {
        //the response is converted to json
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((value) => {
        //iam returning the value here to the promise
        return value;
      });
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
//user.leads is an array of 14 prameters
Promise.all(
  user.leads.map((lead) => {
    //return a new promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(prom(lead)));
  })
)
  //the promise all output
  .then((value) => console.log(value));
```

It returns (14) `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: Why not just `Promise.all(user.leads.map(prom).then(...`? `fetch` returns a promise so maybe the intermediate promise is mucking with it all.

Comment: Wow...! it actually worked thanks alot I was banging my head on it for the past 5hrs... thanks for the replay Drew...